Not be able to delete child tables in SQLAlchemy using in Fast api
Below i have three tables which have many to many relationship between them, the problem is i am not be able to delete user table the database say:
"constraint imagesmetadata_user_id_fkey on table imagesmetadata depends on table users constraint tokens_user_id_fkey on table tokens depends on table userscannot drop table users because other objects depend on it"
The only way i can delete user table after deleting token and images meta data table
Although i already have put this  cascade="all, delete-orphan" in my code but still it doesn't work can some body please help ??
here is my model code:
User file:

from config.Database import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Boolean, String, ForeignKey, DateTime, func, BigInteger
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from model import ImagesMetaData

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, index=True)
    email = Column(String, unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    email_verified = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    picture = Column(String, default=None)
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    tokens = relationship("Token", back_populates="user", cascade="all, delete-orphan")
    images = relationship("ImagesMetaData", back_populates="owner", cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class Token(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tokens'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    access_token = Column(String, nullable=False)
    refresh_token = Column(String, nullable=False)
    expires_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'), nullable=False)
    user = relationship("User", back_populates="tokens")
    created_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = Column(DateTime, default=None)

ImagesMetadata file :
from sqlalchemy import Column, BigInteger, ForeignKey, String, DateTime, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from config.Database import Base
from model import User

class ImagesMetaData(Base):
    __tablename__ = "imagesmetadata"
    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True, nullable=False)
    name = Column(String(200), nullable=False)
    file_type = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    upload_at = Column(DateTime, server_default=func.now())
    Bucket_folder = Column(String, nullable=False)
    user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
    
    # Relationship back to User
    owner = relationship("User", back_populates="images")


Are you trying to drop the entire table or just delete rows from it? Because you mention cascade deletes, which only affect deletes, but your error message looks like you're trying to drop the whole table, in which case cascade deletes won't help you, you need to remove any foreign key relations to it forst.
